# Push to a UIViewController from a presentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I want to push to a new viewcontroller from a presented viewcontroller. I don't want to dismiss the presented viewcontroller. I want the new viewcontroller to come over the presented viewcontroller.

Can anybody tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not push form the presented controller so the best option is

First you have to dismiss the controller without animation and then in the method of -(void)viewWillApper you can easly push to the controller where you want to push.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by using UINavigationController like

```
UINavigationController *vcObject = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewController"];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vcObject animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Now you can easily push or pop to other ViewController like you want.Thankyou

Comment: Are you using UINavigation controller as a rootViewContoller if not than use this code    UINavigationController *nv = [uinavigationcontrollaer]alloc]initwithrootviewcontrolooer:YOUR CONTROLLER];     [self presentViewController:nv animated:YES completion:NULL];

Answer (score 0):

Open your modalView controller as a new rootViewController :

```
UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextViewController];

 [self.navigationController presentViewController: navController animated:YES completion:nil]
```